# Discord.py & Minecraft server ( rcon )

Tags: discord.py, minecraft

вот код

```
from mctools import RCONClient

    @commands.command(name = 'rcon')
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def rcon(self, ctx, *, arg):
        HOST = 'mc.nexil.ru'  
        PORT = 'i eta ne skazy'
        rcon = RCONClient(HOST, port=PORT)
        if rcon.login("ne skazy"):
            resp = rcon.command(arg)
        await ctx.send(f'``{resp}``')
```

Бот выдаёт:

```
[0m[33mСейчас [0m[31;1m0[0m[33m из [0m[31;1m20[0m[33m игроков онлайн
[0m
```

В чём может быть проблема? Первоначально я думал что проблема в кодировке, но это оказалось не так.

Answer (score 0):

С кодом у вас проблем нет.
У вас не отображает цвета ANSI.
Попробуйте включить FORCE_COLOR.

> Мой компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды добавить переменную FORCE_COLOR со значением TRUE

Если это не поможет, то попробуйте погуглить этот вопрос.

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибся.